# A question on groupoids and measurable fields of Hilbert spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, groupoids

Suppose that we have the following data:

- $ \mathcal{G} $ is a locally compact Hausdorff groupoid, with its source and
  range maps denoted by $ s $ and $ r $ respectively.
- $ (\lambda^{x})_{x \in \mathcal{G}^{(0)}} $ is a left Haar system for
  $ \mathcal{G} $.
- $ \mu $ is a quasi-invariant measure on $ \mathcal{G}^{(0)} $.
- $
    \mathfrak{H} \stackrel{\text{df}}{=}
    (\mathcal{H}_{x})_{x \in \mathcal{G}^{(0)}}
    $ is a measurable field of Hilbert spaces over $ \mathcal{G}^{(0)} $.

Now, let $ \nu $ denote the measure on $ \mathcal{G} $ induced by $ \mu $, i.e.,
$$
\forall E \in \mathscr{B}(\mathcal{G}): \qquad
\nu(E) = \int_{\mathcal{G}^{(0)}} {\lambda^{x}}(E) ~ \mathrm{d}{\mu(x)}.
$$
If $ \mathfrak{K} \stackrel{\text{df}}{=} (\mathcal{K}_{\gamma})_{\gamma \in \mathcal{G}} $ denotes the measurable field of Hilbert spaces over $ \mathcal{G} $ such that $ \mathcal{K}_{\gamma} = \mathcal{H}_{r(\gamma)} $ for each $ \gamma \in \mathcal{G} $, then is it necessarily true that the direct integrals
$$
\int_{\mathcal{G}}^{\oplus} \mathcal{K}_{\gamma} ~ \mathrm{d}{\nu(\gamma)}
\qquad \text{and} \qquad
\int_{\mathcal{G}^{(0)}}^{\oplus}
{L^{2}}(\mathcal{G}^{x},\mathcal{H}_{x}) ~
\mathrm{d}{\mu(x)}
$$
are isomorphic as Hilbert spaces? I am asking this because for any $ \displaystyle f \in \int_{\mathcal{G}}^{\oplus} \mathcal{K}_{\gamma} ~ \mathrm{d}{\nu(\gamma)} $, we have
\begin{align*}
    \int_{\mathcal{G}}
    \| f(\gamma) \|_{\mathcal{H}_{r(\gamma)}}^{2} ~
    \mathrm{d}{\nu(\gamma)}
& = \int_{\mathcal{G}^{(0)}}
    \left[
    \int_{\mathcal{G}^{x}}
    \| f(\gamma) \|_{\mathcal{H}_{r(\gamma)}}^{2} ~
    \mathrm{d}{{\lambda^{x}}(\gamma)}
    \right]
    \mathrm{d}{\mu(x)} \\
& = \int_{\mathcal{G}^{(0)}}
    \left\|
    f|_{\mathcal{G}^{x}}
    \right\|_{{L^{2}}(\mathcal{G}^{x},\mathcal{H}_{x})}^{2} ~
    \mathrm{d}{\mu(x)},
\end{align*}
so it appears that one can define a map $ \displaystyle T: \int_{\mathcal{G}}^{\oplus} \mathcal{K}_{\gamma} ~ \mathrm{d}{\nu(\gamma)} \to \int_{\mathcal{G}^{(0)}}^{\oplus} {L^{2}}(\mathcal{G}^{x},\mathcal{H}_{x}) ~ \mathrm{d}{\mu(x)} $ by
$$
\forall
f \in \int_{\mathcal{G}}^{\oplus} \mathcal{K}_{\gamma} ~ \mathrm{d}{\nu(\gamma)},
~ \forall x \in \mathcal{G}^{(0)}: \qquad
[T(f)](x) \stackrel{\text{df}}{=} f|_{\mathcal{G}^{x}}.
$$
Thank you very much for your help!